# tf.gradients applied to pooling wrong result?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a problem in tensorflow with tf.gradients applied to pooling:

[edit]: I was able to reproduce my expectation by changing the equation to:

```
gradpooltest, = tf.gradients((pooltest * pooltest)/2 , [x1])
```

Anyway, I am not sure why I have to do it this way and people answered below do not seem to understand my problem.

```
input x1:
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  2.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -2.  0.  0.  2.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  2.  0.  1.]
 [ 0. -2.  2.  1. -1.  1.]]
pooling test forward:
[[ 2.  2.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  1.]]
 tf.gradients pool test backward:
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
but I expect actually this result by  tf.gradients pool test backward:
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     2     2     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     2     0
 0     1     0     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     1
 0     0     2     0     0     0
```

I don't understand the tf result for tf.gradients pool test backward. (Looks like tensorflow only returns the store matrix for the locations??). Any idea why tf does not return the actual upsampling result?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

#init input-----------------------------------------------------------
init1=np.array([ [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,2,2,2,0,0],
                 [0,-2,0,0,2,1],
                 [0,1,0,1,2,2],
                 [0,1,1,2,0,1],
                 [0,-2,2,1,-1,1] ],dtype="float32")           
init2 = init1.reshape(1,6,6,1)
x1 = tf.Variable(init2)               
#init weight-----------------------------------------------------------
init3 = np.array( [[[[3, 5], [2, -1]]]], dtype="float32")
init4 = init3.reshape(2,2,1,1)
w1 = tf.Variable(init4) 

#init model-----------------------------------------------------------
model = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(model)

#print values-----------------------------------------------------------
print('x1:')
#print sess.run(x6)
x1y = tf.reshape(x1, [6, 6])
print sess.run(x1y)

###################################
#ff: pooling
################################### 
#needs 4D volumes as inputs:
pooltest = tf.nn.max_pool(x1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
print('pooltest:')
#print sess.run(pooltest)
pooltesty = tf.reshape(pooltest, [3, 3])
print sess.run(pooltesty)

###################################
#bw: pooling 
################################### 
#needs 4D volumes as inputs:
gradpooltest, = tf.gradients(pooltest , [x1])
print('gradpooltest:')
#print sess.run(gradpooltest)
gradpooltesty = tf.reshape(gradpooltest, [6, 6])
print sess.run(gradpooltesty)

sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are computing gradients of maxpool operation and this is correct — they are 1 at maximums and 0 at other locations.

Please refer to the following page: http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/#patterns-in-backward-flow

Comment: 2 routed from the "add" gate, "max" gate routed it unchanged to one of it inputs, so the gradient of max gate

Comment: so the gradient of "max" gate is 1 at maximum location and 0 at others.(sorry for a separate comment, can't find a way to edit my previous comment)

Comment: yes so obviously your answer is wrong. see the red 2 routed to z remains a 2

Comment: It is 2 only because of "*2" node. If there were no "*2" node, gradient to "z" would be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your max-pooling operation with a kernel size of `2x2` implemented like:

```
max(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

Where `x1, ..., x4` are the location in the input image under the kernel.

In the forward pass, you extract the maximum value, for example:

```
max(x1, x2, x3, x4) = x2
```

This means that for these 4 variables, in the forward pass only the `x2` variable will be passed trough the network.

In the backward pass, thus, you have only one variable to calculate the derivative and its derivative is `1`.

Therefore the output you got is correct, what do you expect is not.

Comment: look at the link by @dm0. the max gate is a router. maybe you are mixing up relu with pooling??

Comment: The only way to route the gradient is to let it flow trough exactly one input and drop it everywhere else. The only way to let it flow *unchanged* is to multiply the gradient (that comes from the following node of the computational graph) by 1

Comment: check where the input is 0... (4 zeros) right up corner. tf shows a 1 as gradient that is wrong and your answer must be wrong sorry.

Comment: No, it's right. What's the max value between 0 and 0? tf authors decided to pick the first value instead of return an undefined value (because max(x,x) = undefined, in math). Therefore the gradient will flow trough the first cell of that input location

Comment: do we agree that the gradient of zero = 0? max(0,0) = 0? if this is the case then there is only a  gradient of 0 to chain back to the upper right 2x2 window. and this a zero.

Comment: You're not computing the gradient of a value! You're computing the gradient (derivative) of a a **function**. Following your reasoning, the gradient of 1 = 0, so it's the gradient of 2, so it's the gradient of every value. As you can see this is no sense. Instead, you have to understand that you're computing the gradient of a function. This function is y = x where the max value (if any, otherwise the first position) is, 0 otherwise. The derivative of y w.r.t. x is 1.

Comment: ok, good answer: a function (symbolic theano style I suppose?). But this is not what I want. Since I want to get the upsampling result.

Comment: That's another problem. The gradient of the max-pooling op is what you correctly got from TF and it's not an upsampling at all. You have to define your particular operation in order to achieve what you want. Mark an answer as accepted in this thread and open another thread for your other problem.